# Pulling a helm package from AWS ECR in a chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-ecr

Using Helm how do you pull a helm package stored in an AWS ECR: I'm looking to do something like this in my `Chart.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v2
dependencies:
- name: mychart
  repository: 123.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/mychart 
  version: 1.0
```

https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it but let's just clarify a few things.
If your chart is called mychart with image tag 1.0 and your repo is also called mychart then all you have to do for this to work with ECR as the repository is also add the protocol oci as shown here:

```
apiVersion: v2
dependencies:
- name: mychart
  repository: oci://123.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/mychart 
  version: 1.0
```

When you do a `helm dependency build` it will then be able to pull the helm chart (assuming this is a public repo). If it's private you will also need to do a `helm registry login` as shown in [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/push-oci-artifact.html).